# Django view not receiving data from Angularjs $http request

Tags: javascript, python, django, angularjs

I'm using Angular $http to post data to django, but django isn't receiving it. I must be either misusing $http (because this worked with ajax) or my django view is wrong.

```
<div ng-controller="mycontroller2">
    <form ng-submit="submit()">
    {% csrf_token %}
       Search by name:<input ng-model="artiste" />
       <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="artist in artists">
            <td> {({ artist.fields.link })} </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<script>
artApp.controller('mycontroller2', ['$scope', '$http',
function($scope, $http){
    $scope.submit = function(){           

    var postdata = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/rest/',
        data: {
            "artiste": $scope.artiste
        },
        headers: {
            'X-CSRFTOKEN': "{{ csrf_token }}"
        }
    };
    $http(postdata)
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.artists = data;
        })
    }
}]);
</script>
```

The request handler in views.py looks like

```
def rest(request):

    artistname = request.POST.get("artiste") # should get 'da vinci'
    response_data = {}
    response_data = serializers.serialize("json", Art.objects.filter(artist__contains=artistname))
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
```

The error I'm getting from Django is `ValueError at /rest/ Cannot use None as a query value`.

My call to get the value of "artiste" must not be returning 'da vinci' from the `$http` `data` object. I'm sure it's sent successfully because the data `artiste: da vinci` is shown in my headers in devtools. Django just isn't getting that value. Something wrong with the `request.POST.get("artiste")` call?

Comment: have you checked (the "Network" tab on your console) if the data (artiste) is really sent to the server?

Comment: Yes I believe so. In the Network tab it shows the 500 error, I click on that and go to "Headers" and under "Request Payload" it shows `artiste: "da vinci"`. Is that what you are talking about?

Comment: yes.. so it's really a django problem. You'll need to inpect the request object using [pdb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) or [runserver_plus](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/runserver_plus.html)

Comment: I solved it. Since the data is raw json data, I had to get it by doing `json.loads(request.body)` rather than `request.POST.get()`. Shoutout to #django IRC room.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the data from my `$http` request is *raw json data*, my Django request handler had to be changed to deal with that. Now the function (in views.py) looks like

```
def rest(request):

    artistname = json.loads(request.body)      # <- accepts raw json data
    artistname = artistname['artiste']         # <- and now I can pull a value
    response_data = {}
    response_data = serializers.serialize(
                    "json", Art.objects.filter(artist__contains=artistname))

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
```